# Image sequence interface

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspberry-pi-zero

Here's my dilemma. I'm making an interface that is nothing but a series of different image sequences looped together. This interface is meant to be run on a Raspberry Pi. I have it so that when I access different gpio pins on the pi, it loads a different image sequence to be displayed on the screen.

I've been using pygame zero to do this (because I have absolutely no experience in coding in Python at all.) and it's been working well on my PC. However, when I transferred my project over to the pi, it only makes it so far before it freezes. The images are in PNG format and are 480 x 360 resolution running at 60fps.

I have a feeling that the main issue is that the pi only has 512mb of RAM and loading all the images is causing it to freeze.

In pygame zero, is there a way for me to unload the images that I don't need any more to help clear up some ram so it doesn't freeze every time? Or, is there a more efficient way for me to create this interface?

Here's a short video showcasing what I'm talking about.

https://youtu.be/ncDNqqmqBKY

Thank you for taking the time to read this. :)